# Calendar control without postback

Tags: asp.net

I notice the calendar control in ASP.NET does not have an `AutoPostBack` property. I want that when I select a date from the control, the control must `not` post back the page. How do I do that?and one thing more when i hover over on the calender it shows me a script. `"javascript:__doPostBack('Calendar2','5098')"`. So my question is how to disable this javascript to don't `postback` the values

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140200/to-disable-autopostback-for-calender-control-in-asp-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to turn off the `postbacks` to the server but you can use [updatepanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) control which can help you some what.

Answer (score 3):

According to [PLBlum at the ASP.NET forums](http://forums.asp.net/post/1457935.aspx):

> The Calendar control included with ASP.NET uses postbacks only. If you
>   added Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX to the page and put the calendar into an
>   UpdatePanel, it can reduce the appearance of postbacks by using
>   callbacks. But it still makes a trip to the server for each click on a
>   date or month.
>
> Many people have created replacements to the Calendar control that
>   uses javascript to do the work. I am the author of one, in "Peter's
>   Date Package". You can locate others in these sites: the Control
>   Gallery (here under Resources), www.123aspx.com, and www.411asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

You can add like following

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Calendar ID="ad_Cal" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="ad_Cal_SelectionChanged" ></asp:Calendar>

           <asp:Button ID="btn_Del_Day" runat ="server" Text ="Remove Day" OnClick="btn_Del_Day_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" BackColor="#4AA3DF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <asp:Button ID="btn_sort_Date" runat="server" Text="Sort Days" UseSubmitBehavior="False" BackColor="#4AA3DF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" OnClick="btn_sort_Date_Click" />
            <asp:ListBox ID="lst_ad_dates" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

notice that you should use UseSubmitBehavior="False" with buttons also to stop postback for buttons in the same updatePanel

It works fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "CalendarExtender" from **AjaxToolkit**

---

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCalendarExtender" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
<cc3:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar1" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCalendarExtender" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"> 
</cc3:CalendarExtender>
```

---

Remember to add this code at the top of your page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc3" %>
```